# Passing a structure through a named pipe

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I'm trying to pass a struct that contains a string through a named pipe, here's what I'm using so far:

**ClientMessage:*

```
    ClientMessage(const long id, const int action, const std::wstring name)
    : mId(id), mAction(action), mName(name) {};
ClientMessage(std::wstringstream& inputStream) {
    Deserialize(inputStream);
}
~ClientMessage() {};

std::wstringstream& ClientMessage::Serialize(std::wstringstream &out) const
{
    out << mId
        << L'|'
        << mAction
        << L'|'
        << mName.size()
        << L'|'
        << mName.c_str();
    return out;
}

std::wstringstream& ClientMessage::Deserialize(std::wstringstream &in)
{
    if (in) {
        int len = 0;
        wchar_t separator;
        in >> mId;
        in >> separator;
        in >> mAction;
        in >> separator;
        in >> len;
        if (in && len) {
            mName.resize(len);
            in.read(&mName[0], len);
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

**Server:**

```
ClientMessage message(1, 123, L"TestName");

DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
std::wstringstream buffer;
message.Serialize(buffer);
int size = buffer.str().size() * sizeof(WCHAR);
BOOL result = ::WriteFile(this->m_CommPipe, buffer.str().c_str(), size, &bytesWritten, nullptr);
```

**Client**

```
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
int multiplier = 1;
std::vector<WCHAR> buffer;
while(true) {
    DWORD bytesToRead = 1024 * multiplier;
    result = ::ReadFile(pipe, &buffer[0], bytesToRead, &dwBytesRead, nullptr);
    if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == ::GetLastError()) {
        multiplier*=2;
        continue;
    } else if (!result) {
        break;
    }
    std::wstringstream inputStream;
    inputStream.write(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    ClientMessage message(inputStream);
}
```

Before I even try deserializing my data I can see that the string isn't right by checking the contents of inputStream.

Comment: `std::wstring` is non-POD data, you can't write it to a pipe.

Comment: Instead of trying to write a string directly, you need to do a bit more work. Try writing the length of the string, followed by the characters in the string. Use that information on the client side to reconstruct the string.

Comment: `WriteFile` is not smart. It doesn't do anything clever to *serialize* the string. Instead it just writes the string object directly to the pipe. Since that object contains pointers it is meaningless when you try to read it back on the client.

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. There are plenty of Serialization libraries around. Use one.

Comment: Thanks @john I was able to figure it out based on the code snippet above. I was sending the wrong data across the pipe, which is why my end data was corrupted.

Comment: @EJP I could use a library for serialization, but that won't help me understand the core concepts those libraries were built on. I'm just building an application for myself and for knowledge, so using a library for it isn't something I want to do. Thanks though.